# React Hooks Antd props to update

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, antd, react-props

I`m trying to pass the data from a table component to a form that opens when I press the edit button, I know how to do it with react Class but I'm trying with hooks but I still don't understand how to do it.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKf4b.png) is an image of the table.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tZkCz.png) is an image of the form.

Index.js

```
const GestionUsuarios = () => {
  const [data, setData] = React.useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(false);
  const [form] = Form.useForm();
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);
  const [visibleEdit, setVisibleEdit] = useState(false);
  const [users, setUsers] = useState(null);

  const [post, setPost] = React.useState(null);
  const [searchText, setSearchText] = useState('');
  const [searchedColumn, setSearchedColumn] = useState('');

  const columns = [
    {
      title: 'ID',
      dataIndex: 'id',
      sorter: true,
      key: 'id',
      //render: name => `${name.first} ${name.last}`,
      //width: '20%',
    },
    {
      title: 'Tipo de usuario',
      dataIndex: 'tipo',
      filters: [
        { text: 'Administrador', value: '1' },
        { text: 'Supervisor', value: 'super' },
        { text: 'Expedicion Granulado', value: 'expg' },
        { text: 'Expedicion Silo', value: 'exps' },
        { text: 'Lectura', value: 'lectura' },
      ],
    },
    {
      title: 'Nombre',
      dataIndex: 'nombre',
    },
    {
      title: 'Apellido',
      dataIndex: 'apellido',
    },
    {
      title: 'Alias',
      dataIndex: 'username',
    },
    {
      title: 'Email',
      dataIndex: 'email',
    },
    {
      title: 'Action',
      key: 'action',
      fixed: 'right',
      width: 100,
      render: (_, record) => (
        <div>
          <Button
            //onClick={() => retrieveConfig(record.id)}
            onClick={() => {
              setVisibleEdit(true);
            }}
            icon={<EditOutlined />}
          />
        </div>
      ),
    },
    {
      title: '',
      key: 'action2',
      fixed: 'right',
      width: 100,
      render: (_, record) => (
        <Button
          //onClick={() => deleteConfig(record.id, record.test_type)}
          onClick={() => deleteRoute(record.id)}
          icon={<DeleteOutlined />}
        />
      ),
    },
  ];

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('http://localhost:8080/api/usuarios', {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Accept: 'application/json',
      },
    }).then((res) =>
      res.json().then((result) => {
        setUsers(result);
        console.log(result);
      })
    );
  }, []);

  const onEdit = (response, id) => {
    console.log('USUARIO A editar: ', response);
    setVisible(false);
    axios
      .put(`http://localhost:8080/api/usuarios/${id}`, {
        tipo: response.tipo,
        nombre: response.nombre,
        pass: response.pass,
        username: response.username,
        apellido: response.apellido,
        email: response.email,
      })
      .then((response) => {
        setPost(response.data);
        window.location.reload();
      });
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <Button
        onClick={() => {
          setVisible(true);
        }}
        type='primary'
        style={{ marginBottom: 16 }}
      >
        Nuevo usuario
      </Button>
      <AddForm
        visible={visible}
        onCreate={onCreate}
        onCancel={() => {
          setVisible(false);
        }}
      />
      <EditForm
        visible={visibleEdit}
        onCreate={onCreate}
        onCancel={() => {
          setVisibleEdit(false);
        }}
      />
      <Table
        columns={columns}
        dataSource={users}
        pagination={pagination}
        loading={loading}
        rowKey={(record) => record.id}
        //onChange={this.handleTableChange}
        //rowKey="id"
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default GestionUsuarios;
```

EditForm.js

```
const EditFormUsuarios = ({ visible, onCreate, onCancel, props }) => {
  const [form] = Form.useForm();
  const [post, setPost] = React.useState(null);
  const [userID, setUserID] = useState(null);
  const [username, setUsername] = useState('');

  const [dataform, setDatosForm] = useState({
    id: '',
    tipo: '',
    nombre: '',
    apellido: '',
    username: '',
    pass: '',
    email: '',
  });
  const handleUserId = (id) => {
    console.log('ID seleccionado: ', id);
    //setVisible(false);
    axios
      .get(`http://localhost:8080/api/usuarios/${id}`, {
        //.then(response => response.json())
      })
      .then((result) => {
        setUserID(result);
        console.log(result);
        axios.put(`http://localhost:8080/api/usuarios/${result.id}`, {
          tipo: result.tipo,
          nombre: result.nombre,
          apellido: result.apellido,
          username: result.username,
          pass: result.pass,
          email: result.email,
          //.then(response => response.json())
        });
      });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    /*if(this.props.item){
          const { tipo} = this.props.item
          this.setState({ tipo})
        }
        if(this.props.item){
          const { nombre} = this.props.item
          this.setState({ nombre})
        }
        if(this.props.item){
          const { apellido} = this.props.item
          this.setState({ apellido})
        }
        if(this.props.item){
          const { username} = this.props.item
          this.setState({ username})
        }
        if(this.props.item){
          const { pass} = this.props.item
          this.setState({ pass})
        }
        if(this.props.item){
          const { email} = this.props.item
          this.setState({ email})
        }*/
  }, []);
  return (
    <Modal
      {...props}
      visible={visible}
      title='Editar usuario'
      okText='Confirmar'
      cancelText='Cancelar'
      onCancel={onCancel}
      onOk={() => {
        form
          .validateFields()
          .then((values) => {
            form.resetFields();
            onCreate(values);
          })
          .catch((info) => {
            console.log('Validate Failed:', info);
          });
      }}
    >
      <Form
        form={form}
        layout='vertical'
        name='form_in_modal'
        initialValues={{
          modifier: 'public',
        }}
      >
        <Form.Item
          name='id'
          label='Alias'
          rules={[
            {
              required: true,
              message: 'Introduce el alias',
            },
          ]}
          // onChange={e => setUsername(e.target.value)}
          value={dataform && dataform.id}
        ></Form.Item>
        <Form.Item
          name='username'
          label='Alias'
          rules={[
            {
              required: true,
              message: 'Introduce el alias',
            },
          ]}
          onChange={(e) => setUsername(e.target.value)}
          value={dataform && dataform.username}
        >
          <Input />
        </Form.Item>
        <Form.Item
          name='pass'
          label='Contraseña'
          rules={[
            {
              required: true,
              message: 'Introduce la contraseña',
            },
          ]}
        >
          <Input />
        </Form.Item>

        <Form.Item
          name='nombre'
          label='Nombre'
          rules={[
            {
              required: true,
              message: 'Introduce el nombre',
            },
          ]}
        >
          <Input />
        </Form.Item>
        <Form.Item
          name='apellido'
          label='Apellido'
          rules={[
            {
              required: true,
              message: 'Introduce el apellido',
            },
          ]}
        >
          <Input />
        </Form.Item>
        <Form.Item
          name='email'
          label='Email'
          rules={[
            {
              required: true,
              message: 'Introduce el email',
            },
          ]}
        >
          <Input />
        </Form.Item>
        <Form.Item
          name='tipo'
          label='Tipo de usuario'
          rules={[
            {
              required: true,
              message: 'Introduce el tipo de usuario!',
            },
          ]}
        >
          <Input />
        </Form.Item>
      </Form>
    </Modal>
  );
};

export default EditFormUsuarios;
```

Answer (score -1):

from index.js ===>  onCreate={onCreate} ?? add the onEdit or related event  handling function

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).